# Android Studio Flutter Failure with Gradle - Error

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle

**What can I do to solve this error?**
I am coding the login page for my app, I am using SVG. Unfortunately I saw this error.
I used these codes but I did not get any results: `flutter pub cache repair` 
`flutter clean`

```
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
../../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.17.4/lib/src/picture_stream.dart:88:26: Error: Type 'DiagnosticableMixin' not found.
class PictureStream with DiagnosticableMixin {
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.17.4/lib/src/picture_stream.dart:192:44: Error: Type 'DiagnosticableMixin' not found.
abstract class PictureStreamCompleter with DiagnosticableMixin {
                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.17.4/lib/src/picture_stream.dart:88:7: Error: The type 'DiagnosticableMixin' can't be mixed in.
class PictureStream with DiagnosticableMixin {
      ^
../../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.17.4/lib/src/picture_stream.dart:192:16: Error: The type 'DiagnosticableMixin' can't be mixed in.
abstract class PictureStreamCompleter with DiagnosticableMixin {
               ^
../../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.17.4/lib/src/picture_stream.dart:167:11: Error: Superclass has no method named 'debugFillProperties'.
    super.debugFillProperties(properties);
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.17.4/lib/src/picture_stream.dart:171:30: Error: The method 'toStringShort' isn't defined for the class 'PictureStreamCompleter'.
 - 'PictureStreamCompleter' is from 'package:flutter_svg/src/picture_stream.dart' ('../../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.17.4/lib/src/picture_stream.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'toStringShort'.
      ifPresent: _completer?.toStringShort(),
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.17.4/lib/src/picture_stream.dart:266:11: Error: Superclass has no method named 'debugFillProperties'.
    super.debugFillProperties(description);
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\android\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 904

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\android\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 9s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this error using dependency override. Add the following to your `pubspec.yaml`

```
dependency_overrides:
  flutter_svg: 0.18.0
```